# how to assign shifts to the employees using has many association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, has-many, mass-assignment

I have the following models:

1. Shift
2. Employee

The relation between them is as follows:

- shift `has_many` employees.
- an employee `belongs_to` to a shift

I want to have a link which leads to a page that has all the shifts as a dropdown and below that I want to have all the employees with checkboxes.

I want to select a shift from the shift dropdown and I want to select all the employees that belong to that shift by using checkboxes in order to assign that shift to the selected employees.

How can I implement this in Rails?

Comment: paste the code what you are trying to do?

Comment: One implementation might be to use a grid gem. The grid shows an index view and you can filter on for example Shift, where you only show the employees for a specific shift. One gem to implement a grid view is wice_grid, and there are others as well: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Table_Builders. The advantage might be that this way you don't have to write code for a dropdown box (filter) and checkboxes yourself.

Comment: currenty i implemented only this much code   <%= f.collection_select :shift_id, Shift.all, :id ,:shift_name %>.  iam thinking how to implement checkboxes for employess and how to save the selection into database.

Comment: cant we implement this without using any gem?

Comment: how to write a  form for this?what should be the code in the controller to save to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your schema is correct.  Over time, a user will be associated with lots of shifts, and you might want to plan this in advance, so that for example you could assign a single user to lots of different shits, one on each day or something.  For this reason the shifts-employees relationship needs to be **many to many**.  I would have it like this

```
Shift
  has_many :employee_shifts
  has_many :employees, :through => :employee_shifts

Employee
  has_many :employee_shifts
  has_many :shifts, :through => :employee_shifts

EmployeeShift
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :shift
```

Then, when you are assigning shifts, you can either do it by manipulating the `shift_ids` getter/setter for each employee, **or** manipulating the `employee_ids` getter/setter for each shift.

The requirement you talk about is a little complicated because it means that when the shift select is changed, you would need to change the list of checkboxes which is displayed, eg with ajax, since you'd need to check or uncheck the boxes depending on whether employees are assigned to that shift already.  I think it would be nicer to do it as a table, eg showing all shifts in the next week or something. eg

This creates a table with columns for shifts and a row for each employee.
The table sits in a form which will send through a hash like `params[:shifts] = {1 => {:employee_ids => [5,8,10]}, 2 => {:employee_ids => [6,7,8]}}`

```
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Employee</th>
       <% @shifts.each do |shift| %>
         <!-- this is the column header for a single shift. display the appropriate data, i'm guessing here -->
         <th><%= shift.time %></th>
       <% end %>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <% @employees.each do |employee| %>
       <tr>
         <!-- some employee specific data in the first column -->
         <td><%= employee.name %></td>
         <% @shifts.each do |shift| %>
           <td><%= checkbox_tag "shifts[#{shift.id}][employee_ids][]", employee.id, shift.employee_ids.include?(employee.id) %></td>
         <% end %>
       </tr>
     <% end %>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Then, in the controller which this form submits to, you can do something like this:

```
 params[:shifts].each do |id, attributes|
   if shift = Shift.find_by_id(id)
     shift.employee_ids = attributes[:employee_ids] || []
     shift.save
   end
 end
```

Comment: yes i agree. but in my case what i thought is at any given point of time an employee works to only one shift. his shifts may change later, from time to time. but i will change the employee shift manually.i thought like   in a day an employee works for only one shift.

Comment: But that means you can't assign an employee to a shift tomorrow without removing him from all other shifts.    This will just create problems for you.  Do it many-to-many.  That way each employee has a history of shifts going back to when they started working, and a plan of shifts coming up in the future.  You will need this.